# How to get all current android calendar instances

Tags: android, calendar, android-contentprovider

I'm attempting to gather up all currently occurring calendar instances. That is [*instances*](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/CalendarContract.Instances.html), not events nor calendars. I understand how content uris work but they are for querying instances which fall in some time range. I am looking for a way to get instances which begin before now and end after now. Perhaps there is a way to access the table directly like any old sql table?

Extra points if it an be done with a cursor appropriate for populating a ListView with the results.

Comment: Have you found any solution?

Answer (score 0):

There is good [documentation](http://myandroidtutorial.blogspot.tw/2011/12/calendar-provider-at-android.html) about Calendars.

Answer (score 0):

Just query the event instance Cursor:

```
String query = "(" + CalendarContract.Instances.BEGIN + " >= ? ) AND (" + CalendarContract.Instances.END + " <= ? )";
String[] selectionArgs = new String[2];
selectionArgs[0] = startDate.getTime() + "";
selectionArgs[1] = endDate.getTime() + "";
ContentResolver cr = //getContentResolver
Cursor cur = cr.query(CalendarContract.Instances.CONTENT_URI, null, query, selectionArgs, null);
```